# Problem with React and material-ui data-grid in sorting columns

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have problem with sorting data in material-ui data-grid using react. Everything else works fine except sort.

Server side returns json data (example):

[{"cn":["Test User1"],"sn":["testuser1"],"description":["Test desc"],"givenname":["test"],"objectguid":["8672340d-6f00-4bd6-8c5a-ea7e89fee272"],"samaccountname":["test.user1"]},{"cn":["Test User2"],"sn":["testuser2"],"description":["Test desc"],"givenname":["test"],"objectguid":["8672340d-6f00-4bd6-8c5a-ea7e89fee272"],"samaccountname":["test.user2"]}]

Here is my code, pleas help:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { getToken } from '../../utils/Common';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    searchField: {
        width: '100%',
        marginBottom: '10px'
    },
}));

const columns = [
    { field: 'objectguid', headerName: 'GUID', width: 30, hide: true },
    { field: 'samaccountname', headerName: 'Username', width: 130, sortable: true },
    { field: 'givenname', headerName: 'First name', width: 130 },
    { field: 'sn', headerName: 'Last name', width: 130 },
    { field: 'cn', headerName: 'Full name', width: 130 },
    { field: 'description', headerName: 'Description', width: 180 },
];


export default function DataGridDemo() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const [find, setSearchString] = useState("goran");
    const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

    const fechData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/find-user', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken()
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ "find": find })
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {

                    if (result.message) {
                        setRows([]);
                    } else {
                        
                        setRows(result);

                    }


                },

                (error) => {
                    setResult(<div>Error: {error.message}</div>);
                })
        setLoading(false);
    }

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        fechData();
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Search for username" onChange={e => setSearchString(e.target.value)}  className={classes.searchField} />

            </form>

            <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                <DataGrid
                    rows={rows}
                    columns={columns}
                    psnSize={0}
                    getRowId={(row) => row.objectguid}
                    checkboxSelection
                    loading={loading}

                />
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is row.objectguid spelled correctly?